# Why would a while loop in a stored procedure be ignored

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that starts with the following as my while loop:

```
WHILE(SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM LinkDB
          WHERE BaseValue = @Guid
          AND 'PENDING WORKFLOW' = (SELECT TOP(1) Status 
                                FROM BaseDB
                                WHERE UniqueIdentifier IN (SELECT LinkValue
                                               FROM LinkDB
                                               WHERE BaseValue = @Guid))) > 0
```

I have a C# program that executes the above, but if I look in the DB it appears to ignore the while loop at times.  What could be causing this?  If I run the select seperately it returns a value above 0

Comment: select top 1 without specifying order by might not work how you'd expect

Comment: It might help to show the C# code you're using to execute this too as the problem may lie there.

Comment: That whole SELECT looks like it can be hugely simplified from 3 levels of nesting.

Comment: I suppose the other question is why do you think the times it skips the while loop is wrong? It may just be at times it is equal to zero.

Comment: What is this loop doing and can you get rid of it entirely? Looping in a database is horrible for performance and should only be used when absolutely necessary. They can almost always be avoided for dml operations like this one.

Comment: That's a fairly complicated test statement for the WHILE loop. It's likely that even if the data looks like it's there and should hit the loop the WHERE clause is returning zero. Consider re-factoring something into a simpler and more understandable pattern.

Comment: Aside: Using `COUNT` when you only need [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) won't provide any performance gains.

Comment: The reason why I think it skips the loop is because I have a few cases that it skips, but if I manually run the count statement, it does not return zero.  I also can't show the C# code as I don't have access to it, I only compile the SQL scripting. The only reason why I use a while loop is because the contents of what happens after the while loop should occur for every case found that satisfy those conditions, which can be more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is non deterministic
You are not guaranteed to got the same top (1) from run to run

```
SELECT TOP(1) Status 
  FROM BaseDB
 WHERE UniqueIdentifier IN (SELECT LinkValue
                              FROM LinkDB
                             WHERE BaseValue = @Guid)
```

that could be

```
 SELECT TOP(1) Status 
   FROM BaseDB
   JOIN LinkDB 
     ON LinkDB.LinkValue = BaseDB.UniqueIdentifier 
    and LinkDB.BaseValue = @Guid 
--where needed deterministic where
```

-- you sure the whole thing is not this ?

```
 SELECT count(*)
   FROM BaseDB
   JOIN LinkDB 
     ON LinkDB.LinkValue = BaseDB.UniqueIdentifier 
    and LinkDB.BaseValue = @Guid 
    and BaseDB.Status = 'PENDING WORKFLOW'
```